# Order of Functions Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been learning android development with `kotlin` for the last 2 weeks by downloading open source projects from `github` and modifying the source code. [This](https://github.com/anburocky3/Kotlin-Calculator) was the project that I was studying for the past few days. When I was going through the `MainActivity.kt` file, I came across this function (Line 69 in `MainActivity.kt`):

```
fun appendVal(string: String, isClear: Boolean) {
        if (isClear) {
            placeholder.text = ""
            answer.text = ""
//            placeholder.append(string)
        } else {
            placeholder.append(string)
        }
    }
```

Surprisingly, this function was below the `onCreate` function. But if I try the same with python (placing my custom function below `main()`), it would return an error. Here is a demo:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add(1,2))

def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

Why doesn't the same occur in `kotlin`? Does the order of `functions` matter in `kotlin`? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theses are methods and not just some loose functions. And Kotlin is object-orientated and not sequential code.
So the order of methods doesn't matter the least, rather the global/local scope.

Comment: `Theses are methods and not just some loose functions.` -  Can u elaborate on this? And python is also an object-oriented programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Order of functions doesn't matter in **Kotlin** or **Java**, but matters in **Python**. I advise you to locate your python functions to the top of your python script.